# Magento 2 Error after Migration from Magento1.9 to Magento2

Tags: magento2, magento-1.9, data-migration-tool

I have successfully migrated all data with data-migration-tool from Magento 1.9.1.0 to Magento 2.2.4.

After investigation `Admin->Customers->All Customer` ,I am getting error

```
    1 exception(s):
    Exception #0 (BadMethodCallException): Missing required argument $options of Magento\Eav\Model\Entity\Attribute\Source\Config.

    Exception #0 (BadMethodCallException): Missing required argument $options of Magento\Eav\Model\Entity\Attribute\Source\Config.
    #0 /var/www/html/magento2/vendor/magento/framework/ObjectManager/Factory/Dynamic/Developer.php(34): Magento\Framework\ObjectManager\Factory\AbstractFactory->resolveArgumentsInRuntime('Magento\\Eav\\Mod...', Array, Array

)
```

After a lot of Investigation I found some link that have same problems and apply these fixes in my setup but not got any success.

Please Help me.

Comment: is M1 site is multi website? Please check website id in customer table. I have same issue just becuase of website id is no exist in my m2 setup customers are not loading.

Comment: Ok,M1 is multiwebsite,can you please let me know steps?

Comment: What changes you have done @JalpeshPatel.?

Comment: check my answer

Answer (score 0):

Follow the steps below:

1. Create Website, Store and store view.
2. Use the query below.

   UPDATE `customer_entity`
   SET `website_id` = 'Newwebsite id'
   WHERE `customer_entity`.`entity_id` = oldWebsiteId;

[image]

I hope this will help you.

Comment: I have checked Customer attributes in Magento these are migrated in Magento2 but I have not created customer attributes in Magento 2.Hence I have removed from DB and problem resolved now.

Comment: @akgola okay. please add your solution in answer.

Comment: Ok,But now I am getting issue when sign In from frontend "No such entity with email = abcr@gmail.com, websiteId = 1"

Comment: @akgola have you created new website?

Comment: Yes ,I have created.